# UITextField first char was covered

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I use a UITextField in Xcode 9.2 iOS 11.2 in iPAD
When I don't type anything it show as following image

[image]

If I type 'A' , now the String is 'A'

[image]

Then I type 'B', now the String is 'AB'

[image]

Then I type 'C', now the String is 'ABC'

[image]

Then I type 'D', now the String is 'ABCD'

[image]

How can I make it normal ? Thank you!

Comment: I'd say it's maybe a layout issue. Your UITextField starts outside the "view". You can use https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html to check

Comment: is your `UITextField` native instance or a custom subset, what may override certain methods?

Comment: Try to put smaller and more accurate picture instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add  `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];`  in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` as following solve the problem.

```
(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    _animatingView.frame = self.view.bounds;

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]; // I add this line , the problem was solved
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, but I think Larme is right, it sounds like an auto-layout issue, try adjusting the 'leading' property.
You can do so as i did in the following screenshot.

[image: Storyboard - AutoLayout]

Answer (score 0):

Your UITextField x position may be in negative. Its not bounded to your base View.Its coming out of your view. Just check once your UITextField Layout/constraints.